# Is it possible to use app_offline.htm when publishing via ftp?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ftp, publish, visual-studio-extensions, app-offline.htm

Is it possible to configure Visual Studio 2012 to automatically create (and delete) the `app_offline.htm` file when using ftp as the publishing method?

I tried to create the file by hand and add it to the solution (so it would be uploaded automatically and I could delete it by hand once the publishing process is done).
But because it exists in my solution, every request is redirected to it and I can't debug anything.

Changing the name to `app_offline.htm.deactivated` during development and changing it back to `app_offline.htm` before publishing doesn't seem like a perfect solution.

If VS12 doesn't support this natively, I would be happy to use any available extension.

Edit: I noticed, that the `app_offline.htm` file is created when activating `delete all content before publishing` but not when this option isn't selected.

Inserting `<EnableMSDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>` to the `.pubxml` file didn't change anything.

Answer (score -1):

From: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-a-code-update

It says:

> You can configure Web Deploy to automatically put a default app_offline.htm file on the server when it 
>   starts deploying and remove it when it finishes.  To do that all you have to do is add the following XML element to your publish profile (.pubxml) file:

```
<EnableMSDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, please see my edit. How can I configure VS to **always** create the file?

Comment: Then the only thing I can think of that you can do is write a custom MSDeploy script that you run on the command line instead of using the one built into visual studio.  There would basically be 3 lines:  1) msdeploy command to deploy the app_offline.htm, 2) msdeploy to deploy the site, 3) msdeploy to remove the app_offline.htm.  Here is the command line syntax reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569106(v=ws.10).aspx